# How to skip a line every two lines starting by skipping the first line?

Tags: sh

Here's my code : `ls -lt | sed -n 'p;n'`

That code makes me skip from a line to another when listing file names but doesn't start by skipping the first one, how to make that happen?

Here's an exemple without my code to skip to make it clear:

[image]

And here's an exemple of when I use the skip code:
[image]

Comment: `| tail -n +2` gives you everything but the first line of stdin.

Comment: i don't wanna take the everything I wanna skip the first line then take the 2nd then skip the 3rd etc...

Comment: I edited my screenshots i made it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to invert your `sed` command: it should be `n;p` instead of `p;n`:

Your code:

```sh
for x in {1..20}; do echo $x ; done | sed -n 'p;n'
```

```
1
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19
```

The version with `sed` inverted:

```sh
for x in {1..20}; do echo $x ; done | sed -n 'n;p'
```

Output:

```
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
```

Comment: I wanna skip the first line then take the 2nd then skip the 3rd etc... ur code works but not the way it should be

Comment: @MehdiBenabdessalem if I understand correctly, you want to skip the odd lines to keep only the even ones? If so, I edited my answer for this.

Comment: It worked thank you  I replaced the +2 in the tail with a +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed's ~ operator: first~step

```
$ seq 1 10 | sed -n '1~2p'
1
3
5
7
9
```

```
$ seq 1 10 | sed -n '2~2p'
2
4
6
8
10
```